# Multiple MYSQL Queries against one PHP variable

Tags: mysql

I've broken down individual SQL queries for the information I want from my SQL table but I'm confused on how I can combine all statements agianst one variable. This variable is being used in PHP to display my data.

Here is the SQL queries I'm wanting to run.

```
SELECT * FROM weather ORDER BY stamp DESC LIMIT 1 

SELECT SUM(rainfall) FROM weather WHERE stamp >= CURDATE()) AS total_rainfall

SELECT MAX(maxwind) FROM weather WHERE stamp >= CURDATE()) AS max_windspeed

SELECT MAX(temperature) FROM weather WHERE stamp >= CURDATE()) AS max_temperature

SELECT MIN(temperature) FROM weather WHERE stamp >= CURDATE()) AS min_temperature
```

Here is my current query which gives me everything I want except the max windspeed, max temperature, and minimum temperature for the last 24 hours.

```
 SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(rainfall) FROM weather WHERE stamp >= CURDATE()) AS total_rainfall FROM weather ORDER BY stamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Basically, I'm just wanting to add the maximum temperature, minimum temperature and maximum windspeed that occured within the current date.

[MySQL data table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugAp4.png)

Here is the way I'm trying to display the data using PHP.

```
<?php

$url1=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

header("Refresh: 60; URL=$url1");

$connectinfo = mysql_connect("***", "***", "***")
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("raspberrydb001", $connectinfo);

$sql = "SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(rainfall) FROM weatherdata WHERE stamp >= CURDATE()) AS total_rainfall FROM weatherdata ORDER BY stamp DESC LIMIT 1; ";


$result = mysql_query($sql, $connectinfo);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$windspeed = $row['windspeed'];
$maxwind = $row['maxwind'];
$temperature = $row['temperature'];
$humidity = $row['humidity'];
$rainfall = $row['rainfall'];
$stamp = $row['stamp'];
$d=mktime();
$total_rainfall = $row['total_rainfall'];

echo "<div style='text-align:center'><h5>Temperature:  " . $temperature . "(F)" . "<br>" . "Rainfall: " . $total_rainfall . "(in)" . "<br>" . "Wind: " . $windspeed . "(MPH)" . "<br>" .  "Humidity: " . $humidity . "(%)" . "<br>" .  "</h5></div>";
echo "<div style='text-align:right'><h6>Updated at: " . $stamp . "</h6></div>";
echo "<br>";

}

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you add the other queries like you did for total_rainfall ?

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to split it up into two queries.

First, to collect all your data:

```
SELECT * FROM weather ORDER BY stamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Second, to collect the min/max data:

```
SELECT
    SUM(rainfall) AS total_rainfall, 
    MAX(maxwind) AS max_windspeed, 
    MAX(temperature) AS max_temperature, 
    MIN(temperature)  AS min_temperature 
FROM 
    weather
WHERE stamp >= CURDATE())
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Without group by on aggregate function always will return one and only one row, so `limit 1` not needed, also in general limit without order by is meaningless since sql data is unordered.

Comment: I added my PHP block to show how I'm trying to display the data. This has what has me confused.